# Moving from Internal to External page?

Tags: javascript

I've got some code for disabling textfields when radio is not checked working but only using internal coding. Whenever I try putting it on external page it won't work.

Can someone point me where I made mistake?

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById('Ingredient').onchange = disablefield;
document.getElementById('Misc').onchange = disablefield;
document.getElementById('Size').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('Color').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('Brandname').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('Misc').checked = false;
document.getElementById('Ingredient').checked = false;
}

function disablefield()
{
if (document.getElementById('Ingredient').checked == true ){
document.getElementById('Brandname').value = '';
document.getElementById('Size').value = '';
document.getElementById('Color').value = '';
document.getElementById('Size').disabled = true;
document.getElementById('Color').disabled = true;
document.getElementById('Brandname').disabled = false;}

else if (document.getElementById('Misc').checked == true ){
document.getElementById('Brandname').value = '';
document.getElementById('Size').value = '';
document.getElementById('Color').value = '';
document.getElementById('Size').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('Color').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('Brandname').disabled = true;}
}
</script>
```

I did put this code in the head part on html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Additem.js"></script>
```

radio button codes

```
<input name="ItemType" type="radio" value="Ingredient" id="Ingredient" onclick="disablefield()"/>
Ingredient
<input name="ItemType" type="radio" value="Misc" id="Misc" onclick="disablefield()"/>
Misc. Item
```

textfield codes

```
<input type="text" name="Brandname" id="Brandname"/>
<input type="text" name="Size" id="Size"/>
<input type="text" name="Color" id="Color"/>
```

Comment: Are you keeping the script tags in the external page? Is it in the same directory as your page?

Comment: yea..same directory(folder)

Comment: show the content of Additem.js file

Comment: @igor all my javascript codes are on additem.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in the bottom of the document, before the `</body` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Additem.js"></script>
```

Comment: cant put it before the </body> tag since i want it on external page.
like my css.

Comment: I meant the `<script type="text/javascript" src="Additem.js"></script>`